# Writing an ArrayList to BufferedWriter using charArray()

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

The code snippet splits a CSV file into multiple CSV files and writes the first column content to the child CSV files. What I observed with this code is the column header "UNIQUE ID" is only appearing in FIRST CSV file. The following CSV files only contains data without the header. In order to get header to all files I thought of using an ArrayList so that I can put the header at the first index of ArrayList and rest of data afterwards. But I failed miserably.

I require suggestion or help for how to modify the code so that all the child files should have an additional UNIQUE IDENTIFIER row along as the first row with the column data. I am pasting the code which I tried and didn't work. [Child csv should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJFuB.png)  [This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2aoa.png)

```
public static void myFunction(int lines, int files) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {


    String inputfile = "C:/Users/Downloads/CONSOLIDATED.csv";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputfile));
    String strLine = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= files; i++) {

        FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Downloads/FileNumber_" + i + ".csv");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);

        for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++) {

            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine != null) {

                String strar[] = strLine.split(",");
                ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
                al.add(0,"Unique Identifier");
                al.add(1,strar[0]);
                char c[] = al.toString().toCharArray();
                out.write(c);
                out.newLine();
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: How about using open source cvsReader csvWriter ?

Comment: fileWriter = new FileWriter("File"+fileName+".csv");
  csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);
  csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);
  for (String noderef : nodeReflist) {
   List nodeRefDetail = new ArrayList();
   String[] idArray =noderef.split(";");
   nodeRefDetail.add(idArray[0]);
   nodeRefDetail.add(idArray[1]);
             csvFilePrinter.printRecord(nodeRefDetail);
   }

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have done it using csvReader and csvWriter. I want to implement it using coreJava and collections API. Just want to see if it is possible!!

Comment: when you convert the arraylist to a string, you are just using its text representation. you should use a stream or a for loop and a string builder to concatenate the strings

Comment: also please edit your question to include how the original csv looks like and how the split csv files should look like

Comment: @ThijsSteel please see the edit of both how the child file should look and what i am getting after running this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not keeping the headers out of the loops. Try something reading the first line before the main loop and store the headers in the List. then, every time you create a new file, before starting the inner loop, write the header in the first line of each file.

```
public static void myFunction(int lines, int files) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {


    String inputfile = "C:/Users/Downloads/CONSOLIDATED.csv";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputfile));
    String strLine = br.readLine(); //here you have the headers
    String[] headers=strLine.split(",");

    for (int i = 1; i <= files; i++) {

        FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Downloads/FileNumber_" + i + ".csv");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);

        out.write(headers[0]);

        for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++) {
            out.newLine();
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine != null) {

              String strar[] = strLine.split(",");
              out.write(strar[0]);
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: @Pablo...thank you for your effort.As u suggested in the answer,I am confused about this part though... "then, every time you create a new file, before starting the inner loop, write the header in the first line of each file." How to achieve this with arrayList. I am unable to think of any approach. Also checked all the methods related to List but could not find anything helpful..

Comment: Tried as you suggested. It failed to meet the purpose @Pablo

Comment: I was not sure what the output files format is, so I just wrote the general idea. I've updated the method

Comment: Thank you....It is working as expected. The files are generated but it is giving a NULL POINTER exception. I am trying to figure it out